# Select from multiple tables with group and join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, inner-join

i have 4 tabels

drinks, opskrifter, ingredients and stock

the tables consist of

drinks

- drink_id
- name
- beskriv
- glas
- image
- alcohol

opskrifter

- drink_id
- ingredient_id
- quantity

ingredients

- ingredient_id
- name

stock

- ingredient_id
- name

i want a query to select drinks that can be made in opskrifter of the ingredients in stock.

i have this working, but it only returns drink_id.

```
select o.drink_id
from opskrifter o
left join stock s on s.ingredient_id = o.ingredient_id 

group by o.drink_id
having count(*) = count(s.ingredient_id)
```

**I want it to return:**

drink_id, name, beskriv, glas, image, alcohol

somebody help my on the way :-) thx

Comment: I don't get it - are you looking for drinks which use all the ingredients in stock?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yes im looking for drinks with all ingredients in stock. The query above is working, i just want to return more info from it than only drink_id. i want name etc.. from the drinks table. i just cant figure out how?

Comment: Put your query into a cte then in the main query joining the other tables you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to bring the `drink` table. I would just use a `join` for that, while turning the aggregate query to a subquery:

```
select d.*, o.cnt_ingredients
from drink d
inner join (
    select o.drink_id, count(*) as cnt_ingredients
    from opskrifter o
    left join stock s on s.ingredient_id = o.ingredient_id 
    group by o.drink_id
    having count(*) = count(s.ingredient_id) 
) o on o.drink_id = d.drink_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add them to the list after `SELECT` and to the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT o.drink_id,
       o.name,
       o.beskriv,
       o.glas,
       o.image,
       o.alcohol
...
       GROUP BY o.drink_id,
                o.name,
                o.beskriv,
                o.glas,
                o.image,
                o.alcohol
...
```

If `drink_id` is a key, it might also be enough to list only `drink_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your query does work, you should calculate the number of ingredients used and the number that exist and you could use a cte then join for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS drinks,OPSKRIFTER,ingredients,stock;
create table drinks
(drink_id int,
name varchar(3),
beskriv int,
glas int,
image varchar(10),
alcohol int
);
create table opskrifter
(drink_id int,
ingredient_id int,
quantity int
);

create table ingredients
(ingredient_id int,
name varchar(3)
);

create table stock
(ingredient_id int,
name varchar(3)
);

insert into drinks(drink_id,name) values (1,'n1'),(2,'n2');
insert into opskrifter values (1,1,10),(1,2,10),(2,1,20);
insert into stock values(1,'i1'),(2,'I2');

with cte as
(
select o.drink_id,count(*) cnt,(Select count(*) from stock) sn
from opskrifter o
group by o.drink_id having cnt = sn
)
select drinks.drink_id,drinks.name
from cte
join drinks on drinks.drink_id = cte.drink_id;

+----------+------+
| drink_id | name |
+----------+------+
|        1 | n1   |
+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```